# Get HDMI EDID data

Tags: android, hdmi, edid

I am developing an application which mirrors itself to any connected HDMI monitor using MHL adapter.
The issue is that I need to get the monitor data like manufacturer, serial no., resolution, screen size etc. if it is really displaying my content or it is just on another HDMI input.